# Rails Factory Girl with Circular Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, factory-bot

I have two models with circular relationships. How do I model these in Factory Girl?

I am getting too many error messages, trying to do this.

Models:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: "User", inverse_of: :account
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
end
```

Factories:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user, aliases: [:owner] do
    sequence(:email) { |n| "user#{n}@example.com" }
    password "test"
    password_confirmation "test"
    account
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :account do |account|
    account.name "My School"
    account.short_name "school1"
    account.sequence(:subdomain) { |n| "school#{n}" }
    account.owner { FactoryGirl.build(:user, account: account) }
  end
end
```

I get the following error:

```
 Failure/Error: let!(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `primary_key' for #<FactoryGirl::Declaration::Implicit:0x00000007bd9050>
 # ./spec/factories/accounts.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Can you help with this error?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:email) { |n| "user#{n}@example.com" }
    password "test"
    password_confirmation "test"
    association :account
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :account do
    name "My School"
    short_name "school1"
    sequence(:subdomain) { |n| "school#{n}" }
    association :owner, factory: :user
  end
end
```

Comment: I get the stack too deep error: `Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace SystemStackError: stack level too deep`

Comment: doh! - updated answer, was missing `:` on `association :owner, factory: :user`

Comment: Yeah. I added that before testing

Comment: @ZiaUlRehmanMughal why would this work? There's a circular dependency.